# How to get a direct link to "Create your account" page without entering your email

Tags: php, hyperlink, prestashop, account

aaHey everyone, hope you  doing well :)

I'm wanting to make the Create Your Account page as a link without entering your email that takes you to a separate registration page.

I have created a new controller and template file with name "inscription" and there is the codes

```
class InscriptionControllerCore extends FrontController
{
public $auth = true;
public $php_self = 'inscription';
public $authRedirection = 'inscription';
public $ssl = true;

    public function init()
{
    parent::init();


    if (Tools::getValue('create_account'))
        $this->create_account = true;
}

public function setMedia()
{
    parent::setMedia();
    $this->addCSS(_THEME_CSS_DIR_.'authentification.css');
}


/**
 * Assign template vars related to page content
 * @see FrontController::initContent()
 */
public function initContent()
{
    parent::initContent();

    $this->context->smarty->assign('genders', Gender::getGenders());

    $this->assignDate();

    $this->assignCountries();

    $active_module_newsletter = false;
    if ($module_newsletter = Module::getInstanceByName('blocknewsletter'))
        $active_module_newsletter = $module_newsletter->active;

    $this->context->smarty->assign('newsletter', (int)$active_module_newsletter);


    if (Tools::getValue('display_guest_checkout'))
    {
        if (Configuration::get('PS_RESTRICT_DELIVERED_COUNTRIES'))
            $countries = Carrier::getDeliveredCountries($this->context->language->id, true, true);
        else
            $countries = Country::getCountries($this->context->language->id, true);

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']))
        {
            $array = preg_split('/,|-/', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
            if (!Validate::isLanguageIsoCode($array[0]) || !($sl_country = Country::getByIso($array[0])))
                $sl_country = (int)Configuration::get('PS_COUNTRY_DEFAULT');
        }
        else
            $sl_country = (int)Tools::getValue('id_country', Configuration::get('PS_COUNTRY_DEFAULT'));

        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                'inOrderProcess' => true,
                'PS_GUEST_CHECKOUT_ENABLED' => Configuration::get('PS_GUEST_CHECKOUT_ENABLED'),
                'PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE' => Configuration::get('PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE'),
                'sl_country' => (int)$sl_country,
                'countries' => $countries
            ));
    }

    if (Tools::getValue('create_account'))
        $this->context->smarty->assign('email_create', 1);
        $this->context->smarty->assign('type_account', 1);

    if (Tools::getValue('multi-shipping') == 1)
        $this->context->smarty->assign('multi_shipping', true);
    else
        $this->context->smarty->assign('multi_shipping', false);

    $this->assignAddressFormat();

    // Call a hook to display more information on form
    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'HOOK_CREATE_ACCOUNT_FORM' => Hook::exec('displayCustomerAccountForm'),
            'HOOK_CREATE_ACCOUNT_TOP' => Hook::exec('displayCustomerAccountFormTop')
        ));

    if ($this->ajax)
    {
        // Call a hook to display more information on form
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                'PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE' => Configuration::get('PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE'),
                'genders' => Gender::getGenders()
            ));

        $return = array(
            'hasError' => !empty($this->errors),
            'errors' => $this->errors,
            'page' => $this->context->smarty->fetch(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'authentication.tpl'),
            'token' => Tools::getToken(false)
        );
        die(Tools::jsonEncode($return));
    }
    $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'authentication.tpl');
}

    protected function assignDate()
{
    // Generate years, months and days
    if (isset($_POST['years']) && is_numeric($_POST['years']))
        $selectedYears = (int)($_POST['years']);
    $years = Tools::dateYears();
    if (isset($_POST['months']) && is_numeric($_POST['months']))
        $selectedMonths = (int)($_POST['months']);
    $months = Tools::dateMonths();

    if (isset($_POST['days']) && is_numeric($_POST['days']))
        $selectedDays = (int)($_POST['days']);
    $days = Tools::dateDays();

    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'one_phone_at_least' => (int)Configuration::get('PS_ONE_PHONE_AT_LEAST'),
            'onr_phone_at_least' => (int)Configuration::get('PS_ONE_PHONE_AT_LEAST'), //retro compat
            'years' => $years,
            'sl_year' => (isset($selectedYears) ? $selectedYears : 0),
            'months' => $months,
            'sl_month' => (isset($selectedMonths) ? $selectedMonths : 0),
            'days' => $days,
            'sl_day' => (isset($selectedDays) ? $selectedDays : 0)
        ));

if (Tools::isSubmit('SubmitCreate'))
        $this->processSubmitCreate();

}

protected function processSubmitAccount()
{

    $this->create_account = true;
    if (Tools::isSubmit('submitAccount'))
        $this->context->smarty->assign('email_create', 1);
        $this->context->smarty->assign('type_account', 1);
    // New Guest customer
    if (!Tools::getValue('is_new_customer', 1) && !Configuration::get('PS_GUEST_CHECKOUT_ENABLED'))
        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('You cannot create a guest account..');
    if (!Tools::getValue('is_new_customer', 1))
        $_POST['passwd'] = md5(time()._COOKIE_KEY_);
    if (isset($_POST['guest_email']) && $_POST['guest_email'])
        $_POST['email'] = $_POST['guest_email'];
    // Checked the user address in case he changed his email address
    if (Validate::isEmail($email = Tools::getValue('email')) && !empty($email))
        if (Customer::customerExists($email))
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An account using this email address has already been registered.', false);
    // Preparing customer
    $customer = new Customer();
    $customer->profile_pic='0';
    $lastnameAddress = Tools::getValue('lastname');
    $firstnameAddress = Tools::getValue('firstname');       
    $_POST['lastname'] = Tools::getValue('customer_lastname');
    $_POST['firstname'] = Tools::getValue('customer_firstname');
    $_POST['num_rc'] = Tools::getValue('num_rc');

    $error_phone = false;
    if (Configuration::get('PS_ONE_PHONE_AT_LEAST'))
    {
        if (Tools::isSubmit('submitGuestAccount') || !Tools::getValue('is_new_customer'))
        {
            if (!Tools::getValue('phone') && !Tools::getValue('phone_mobile'))
                $error_phone = true;
        }
        elseif (((Configuration::get('PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE') || Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE')) 
                && (Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE') && !Tools::getValue('email_create')))
                && (!Tools::getValue('phone') && !Tools::getValue('phone_mobile')))
            $error_phone = true;
        elseif (((Configuration::get('PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE') && Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE') && Tools::getValue('email_create')))
                && (!Tools::getValue('phone') && !Tools::getValue('phone_mobile')))
            $error_phone = true;
    }

    if ($error_phone)
        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('You must register at least one phone number.');

    $this->errors = array_unique(array_merge($this->errors, $customer->validateController()));

    // Check the requires fields which are settings in the BO
    $this->errors = array_merge($this->errors, $customer->validateFieldsRequiredDatabase());

    if (!Configuration::get('PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE') && !$this->ajax && !Tools::isSubmit('submitGuestAccount'))
    {
        if (!count($this->errors))
        {
            if (Tools::isSubmit('newsletter'))
                $this->processCustomerNewsletter($customer);

            $customer->birthday = (empty($_POST['years']) ? '' : (int)$_POST['years'].'-'.(int)$_POST['months'].'-'.(int)$_POST['days']);
            if (!Validate::isBirthDate($customer->birthday))
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Invalid date of birth.');

            // New Guest customer
            $customer->is_guest = (Tools::isSubmit('is_new_customer') ? !Tools::getValue('is_new_customer', 1) : 0);
            $customer->active = 1;

            if (!count($this->errors))
            {
                if ($customer->add())
                {


                    if (!$customer->is_guest)
                        if (!$this->sendConfirmationMail($customer))
                            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('The email cannot be sent.');

                    $this->updateContext($customer);

                    $this->context->cart->update();
                    Hook::exec('actionCustomerAccountAdd', array(
                            '_POST' => $_POST,
                            'newCustomer' => $customer
                        ));
                    if ($this->ajax)
                    {
                        $return = array(
                            'hasError' => !empty($this->errors),
                            'errors' => $this->errors,
                            'isSaved' => true,
                            'id_customer' => (int)$this->context->cookie->id_customer,
                            'id_address_delivery' => $this->context->cart->id_address_delivery,
                            'id_address_invoice' => $this->context->cart->id_address_invoice,
                            'token' => Tools::getToken(false)
                        );
                        die(Tools::jsonEncode($return));
                    }

                    if ($back = Tools::getValue('back'))
                        Tools::redirect(html_entity_decode($back));
                    // redirection: if cart is not empty : redirection to the cart
                    if (count($this->context->cart->getProducts(true)) > 0)
                        Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order&multi-shipping='.(int)Tools::getValue('multi-shipping'));
                    // else : redirection to the account
                    else
                        Tools::redirect('index.php?controller='.(($this->authRedirection !== false) ? url_encode($this->authRedirection) : 'my-account'));
                }
                else
                    $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occurred while creating your account..');
            }
        }

    }
    else // if registration type is in one step, we save the address
    {
        // Preparing address
        $address = new Address();
        $_POST['lastname'] = $lastnameAddress;
        $_POST['firstname'] = $firstnameAddress;
        $address->id_customer = 1;
        $this->errors = array_unique(array_merge($this->errors, $address->validateController()));

        // US customer: normalize the address
        if ($address->id_country == Country::getByIso('US'))
        {
            include_once(_PS_TAASC_PATH_.'AddressStandardizationSolution.php');
            $normalize = new AddressStandardizationSolution;
            $address->address1 = $normalize->AddressLineStandardization($address->address1);
            $address->address2 = $normalize->AddressLineStandardization($address->address2);
        }

        if (!($country = new Country($address->id_country)) || !Validate::isLoadedObject($country))
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Country cannot be loaded with address->id_country');
        $postcode = Tools::getValue('postcode');        
        /* Check zip code format */
        if ($country->zip_code_format && !$country->checkZipCode($postcode))
            $this->errors[] = sprintf(Tools::displayError('The Zip/Postal code you\'ve entered is invalid. It must follow this format: %s'), str_replace('C', $country->iso_code, str_replace('N', '0', str_replace('L', 'A', $country->zip_code_format))));
        elseif(empty($postcode) && $country->need_zip_code)
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('A Zip / Postal code is required.');
        elseif ($postcode && !Validate::isPostCode($postcode))
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('The Zip / Postal code is invalid.');

        if ($country->need_identification_number && (!Tools::getValue('dni') || !Validate::isDniLite(Tools::getValue('dni'))))
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('The identification number is incorrect or has already been used.');
        elseif (!$country->need_identification_number)
            $address->dni = null;
    }

    if (!@checkdate(Tools::getValue('months'), Tools::getValue('days'), Tools::getValue('years')) && !(Tools::getValue('months') == '' && Tools::getValue('days') == '' && Tools::getValue('years') == ''))
        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Invalid date of birth');

    if (!count($this->errors))
    {
        if (Customer::customerExists(Tools::getValue('email')))
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An account using this email address has already been registered. Please enter a valid password or request a new one. ', false);
        if (Tools::isSubmit('newsletter'))
            $this->processCustomerNewsletter($customer);

        $customer->birthday = (empty($_POST['years']) ? '' : (int)$_POST['years'].'-'.(int)$_POST['months'].'-'.(int)$_POST['days']);
        if (!Validate::isBirthDate($customer->birthday))
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Invalid date of birth');

        if (!count($this->errors))
        {
            // if registration type is in one step, we save the address
            if (Configuration::get('PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE') || Tools::isSubmit('submitGuestAccount'))
                if (!($country = new Country($address->id_country, Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'))) || !Validate::isLoadedObject($country))
                    die(Tools::displayError());
            $contains_state = isset($country) && is_object($country) ? (int)$country->contains_states: 0;
            $id_state = isset($address) && is_object($address) ? (int)$address->id_state: 0;
            if (Configuration::get('PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE') && $contains_state && !$id_state)
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('This country requires you to chose a State.');
            else
            {
                $customer->active = 1;
                // New Guest customer
                if (Tools::isSubmit('is_new_customer'))
                    $customer->is_guest = !Tools::getValue('is_new_customer', 1);
                else
                    $customer->is_guest = 0;
                if (!$customer->add())
                    $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occurred while creating your account..');
                else
                {
                    $address->id_customer = (int)$customer->id;
                    $this->errors = array_unique(array_merge($this->errors, $address->validateController()));
                    if (!count($this->errors) && (Configuration::get('PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE') || $this->ajax || Tools::isSubmit('submitGuestAccount')) && !$address->add())
                        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occurred while creating your address.');
                    else
                    {
                        if (!$customer->is_guest)
                        {
                            $this->context->customer = $customer;
                            $customer->cleanGroups();
                            // we add the guest customer in the default customer group
                            $customer->addGroups(array((int)Configuration::get('PS_CUSTOMER_GROUP')));
                            if (!$this->sendConfirmationMail($customer))
                                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('The email cannot be sent.');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $customer->cleanGroups();
                            // we add the guest customer in the guest customer group
                            $customer->addGroups(array((int)Configuration::get('PS_GUEST_GROUP')));
                        }
                        $this->updateContext($customer);
                        $this->context->cart->id_address_delivery = Address::getFirstCustomerAddressId((int)$customer->id);
                        $this->context->cart->id_address_invoice = Address::getFirstCustomerAddressId((int)$customer->id);

                        // If a logged guest logs in as a customer, the cart secure key was already set and needs to be updated
                        $this->context->cart->update();

                        // Avoid articles without delivery address on the cart
                        $this->context->cart->autosetProductAddress();

                        Hook::exec('actionCustomerAccountAdd', array(
                                '_POST' => $_POST,
                                'newCustomer' => $customer
                            ));
                        if ($this->ajax)
                        {
                            $return = array(
                                'hasError' => !empty($this->errors),
                                'errors' => $this->errors,
                                'isSaved' => true,
                                'id_customer' => (int)$this->context->cookie->id_customer,
                                'id_address_delivery' => $this->context->cart->id_address_delivery,
                                'id_address_invoice' => $this->context->cart->id_address_invoice,
                                'token' => Tools::getToken(false)
                            );
                            die(Tools::jsonEncode($return));
                        }
                        // if registration type is in two steps, we redirect to register address
                        if (!Configuration::get('PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE') && !$this->ajax && !Tools::isSubmit('submitGuestAccount'))
                            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=address');

                        if ($back = Tools::getValue('back'))
                            Tools::redirect(html_entity_decode($back));

                        // redirection: if cart is not empty : redirection to the cart
                        if (count($this->context->cart->getProducts(true)) > 0)
                            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order&multi-shipping='.(int)Tools::getValue('multi-shipping'));
                        // else : redirection to the account
                        else
                            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller='.(($this->authRedirection !== false) ? url_encode($this->authRedirection) : 'my-account'));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (count($this->errors))
    {
        //for retro compatibility to display guest account creation form on authentication page
        if (Tools::getValue('submitGuestAccount'))
            $_GET['display_guest_checkout'] = 1;

        if (!Tools::getValue('is_new_customer'))
            unset($_POST['passwd']);
        if ($this->ajax)
        {
            $return = array(
                'hasError' => !empty($this->errors),
                'errors' => $this->errors,
                'isSaved' => false,
                'id_customer' => 0
            );
            die(Tools::jsonEncode($return));
        }
        $this->context->smarty->assign('account_error', $this->errors);
    }
}

/**
 * Assign countries var to smarty
 */
protected function assignCountries()
{
    if (isset($this->create_account))
    {
        // Select the most appropriate country
        if (isset($_POST['id_country']) && is_numeric($_POST['id_country']))
            $selectedCountry = (int)($_POST['id_country']);
        /* FIXME : language iso and country iso are not similar,
         * maybe an associative table with country an language can resolve it,
         * But for now it's a bug !
         * @see : bug #6968
         * @link:http://www.prestashop.com/bug_tracker/view/6968/
         elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']))
         {
         $array = explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
         if (Validate::isLanguageIsoCode($array[0]))
         {
         $selectedCountry = Country::getByIso($array[0]);
         if (!$selectedCountry)
         $selectedCountry = (int)(Configuration::get('PS_COUNTRY_DEFAULT'));
         }
         }*/
        if (!isset($selectedCountry))
            $selectedCountry = (int)(Configuration::get('PS_COUNTRY_DEFAULT'));

        if (Configuration::get('PS_RESTRICT_DELIVERED_COUNTRIES'))
            $countries = Carrier::getDeliveredCountries($this->context->language->id, true, true);
        else
            $countries = Country::getCountries($this->context->language->id, true);
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                'countries' => $countries,
                'PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE' => Configuration::get('PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE'),
                'sl_country' => (isset($selectedCountry) ? $selectedCountry : 0),
                'vat_management' => Configuration::get('VATNUMBER_MANAGEMENT')
            ));
    }
}

/**
 * Assign address var to smarty
 */
protected function assignAddressFormat()
{
    $addressItems = array();
    $addressFormat = AddressFormat::getOrderedAddressFields(Configuration::get('PS_COUNTRY_DEFAULT'), false, true);
    $requireFormFieldsList = AddressFormat::$requireFormFieldsList;

    foreach ($addressFormat as $addressline)
        foreach (explode(' ', $addressline) as $addressItem)
        $addressItems[] = trim($addressItem);

    // Add missing require fields for a new user susbscription form
    foreach ($requireFormFieldsList as $fieldName)
        if (!in_array($fieldName, $addressItems))
            $addressItems[] = trim($fieldName);

    foreach (array('inv', 'dlv') as $addressType)
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array($addressType.'_adr_fields' => $addressFormat, $addressType.'_all_fields' => $addressItems));
}}
```

What I get when I enter to :mysite/index.php?controller=inscription it directly redirect me to mysite/index.php?control

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I have created a new page (tpl) and controller with a name "inscription" same as authentication without the email and logged stuff but then nothing happens. I wish if there is another better way like to get directly a link or something with no new page creation

Comment: Can you show what you have tried, so that we can help you?

Comment: Ok can I just ask you guys _I have an idea_
Why when entering to "authentification page" the form of "acount-creation" and other forms that exist in "authentification.tpl" are not displayed, I have cheked and there is nothing such as display:none or something for this forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by the way it is in this line

```
public $auth = true;
```

I should have removed it !! when I did it worked fine, thank you anyway

Answer (score 2):

You can get the direct link to the Create Account form adding the parameter **create_account=1**, this will skip the email verification and go directly to the form.

For example:

```
{$link->getPageLink('authentication', true)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}?create_account=1
```